# How to merge arrays that derive from the same variable

Tags: javascript

I have the following line of code which returns me one or more arrays depending on the checkbox that is clicked.

```js
selected.forEach(langsel => {
                let filtered = person.filter(pers => pers.language == langsel);
            })
```

*selected* and I do not report the other variables for simplicity in reading.

I have a list of checkboxes where each refers to a particular language. So every time a checkbox is clicked I want the people who speak that language to be returned to me; this must be returned in an array of objects.

*catsel* refers to the checkbox that is selected (being a checkbox, more than one can also be selected). So for each language that is selected it returns me the array of objects in the *filtered* variable.

For example, if I select the English language through the checkbox, I get:

> [{id: "2", name: "Tomas Addreh", language: "English"},{id: "6", name: "Mark Addreh", language: "English"}];

if together with the checkbox selected previously, therefore English, I also select the checkbox relating to the Spanish language, *filtered* returns me:

> [{id: "2", name: "Tomas Addreh", language: "English"},{id: "6", name: "Mark Addreh", language: "English"}];
>
> [{id: "15", name: "Alex Atres", language: "Spanish"}, {id: "1", name: "Mark Sertoj", language: "Spanish"}, id: "12", name: "Martha Forrest", language: "Spanish"];

*filtered* in the latter case returns me two separate arrays.

I want them **to be merged into an array**.

Can anyone kindly help me?

Comment: `concat` should do the trick?

Comment: You would need another variable to store the person. If new language checked, it append to the variable.

Comment: @JackBashford as the number of arrays can vary how can I do with concat? can you kindly show me how to do?

Comment: @markcc can you kindly show me how to do?

Comment: Check the docs @Aurora https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Comment: @JackBashford I have already seen this. The problem is that I don't have a fixed number of arrays because the latter depends on the checkboxes that are selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I concat the array by using spread operator.

```
let people = [];
selected.forEach(langsel => {
    let filteredPerson = person.filter(pers => pers.language == langsel);
    people = [...people, ...filteredPerson];
})
```

Comment: It works, thanks. What are the ...?

Comment: It's a spread operator